# Significado de “echarse una novia”

Tags: definiciones, significado

En el [Reverso Dictionary](https://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/echarse+una+novia) he encontrado:

> **Echarse** **(uso enfático)**
>
> echarse una novia (to get o.s. a girlfriend)

¿Por qué dice que se trata de un uso enfático del vocablo “echarse"? ¿Cómo puede enfatizar?

Answer (score 3):

Ignoro por qué ese diccionario indica que es un uso enfático del verbo *echar*.

Según el diccionario de la RAE, la acepción que buscas dice simplemente:

> **[echar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EJtx4Yo)**
>
> 48. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Entablar determinada relación con otra. *Echarse novia. Echarse un amigo.*

Esta acepción es muy reciente, presente en el diccionario desde 1970 con casi la misma redacción. En ningún momento se ha indicado que es un uso enfático.

Como curiosidad, el caso más antiguo que he encontrado en el CORDE es de principios del siglo XX:

> *Es un momento solemne el de la entrada en la segunda enseñanza. Para unos marca el uso del pantalón largo, para otros el del reló, para casi todos el principio de la edad del pavo y de echarse novia, para algunos el de las concupiscencias del saber.*
>
> Miguel de Unamuno, "Recuerdos de niñez y de mocedad", 1908 (España).

Answer (score 2):

Yo diría que hace énfasis por las connotaciones del verbo.

Echarse una novia significa "conseguir" una novia. Es comenzar una relación, sí, pero denota un cierto "logro". Por eso digo que significa "conseguir". Por ejemplo

```
La invitó a tomar café y a los pocos días se la echó de novia.
```

Tiene connotaciones de "ganar", en definitiva. Por eso puede ser algo enfático; aunque más que énfasis, yo creo que simplemente es que tiene este significado de "conseguir". Por cierto, es una expresión informal.

Comment: Curioso, nunca le vi esta connotación de "conseguir", "lograr" o "ganar".

Comment: hay otras como "dirigir" y "alcanzar"

Answer (score 1):

En este sentido, "echarse" tiene el significado de comenzar.  Puede enfatizar que no comiences una relación.  Es una recomendación dura y enfática.

Igual como este:

> Te recomiendo que no comiences una relación con una novia por que te costará mucho dinero.

http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/echar

> 29.) Entablar determinada relación con una persona:
>
> echarse novia.

Answer (score 0):

**¡Echarse novio/a!**

---

Los antiguos recuerdos que tengo sobre el tema apenas si guardan relación con lo que aquí se apunta, es decir "comenzar una relación de tipo amoroso con otra persona".

Este tipo de escenas siempre las recuerdo alrededor de la chimenea de mi infancia, pues fuera de aquel habitáculo que estaba caldeado, las demás habitaciones de la casa estaban congeladas e ir por ellas era un martirio. Recuerdo que habitualmente era una vecina la que traía la "buena nueva", mientras que se acercaba a calentarse y nos daba los detalles de la "ocurrencia".

No se por qué no me extraña que se incida en el "carácter enfático" de la voz, en este caso "echarse", pues normalmente se echa algo física -o- figurativamente y de esta forma la "persona" queda afectado en uno u otro sentido, como posible problema que puede aparecer en un momento dado ó incluso como muestra de orgullo por las cualidades o actos recibidos.

Las entrañables y antiguas escenas aproximadamente rondaban de esta forma;

- "Sabéis que Ramoncin se ha echao como novia a la hija del piconero."
- ¿Quien? La de Julian, ¿Rosa?, no Paquita, la hija más pequeña...
- ¿no me digas?
- Más tarde saltaba mi bisabuelo pensativo, dudando de lo que iba a decir, mientras hacia algo con las manos, pues ya sabe el Ramoncin, que tenga cuidao, porque como se quede preña la niña, conociendo a Julian el Piconero y a la familia de la niña, esos no se andan con tonterías y los echan a los dos fuera de la casa.
- Mi bisabuela siempre andaba con lo mismo, e intentaba suavizar la situación, "Madre de Dio"s, unas criaturicas solas, sin que nadie las atienda, que si así no podía vivir una familia, que era muy difícil llevar algo a casa, que todo estaba por las nubes, que aunque la vida esta dura la gente suele tener novia y casarse, ¿no lo hicimos nosotros?, reponía ella.
- Y salía mi bisabuelo, si pero te tuve que ir a raptar y salir antes de que se enterara tu padre, que si nos coge, aún estas allí.

La conversación podía mantenerse por horas sobre la misma rúbrica sin añadir casi nada novedoso, al hecho de que "Ramoncin se había echado novia", a no ser que otra vecina entrara con nuevas entregas....

---

La expresión "echarse novia" la conocí después de la guerra civil, pero sin duda seria más antigua, aunque en estos contextos un tanto críticos. La vida dura de entonces, el escaso trabajo, lo difícil que era ahorrar para comprar cualquier cosa, sin hablar de los problemas derivados de la diferencia de clase ó los peligros de un embarazo no deseado.

En mi niñez, siempre entendí que en ese " Fulanito, se había echado novia" ó que "Menganita se ha echado novio", no llevaba aparejada una gran alegría de la que todos poder alegrarse, como un día de bautizo ó una lotería. Más bien todo lo contrarío. Era como si la suerte de una persona se hubiera detenido por un momento y ahora eran sus actos los que jugaban más que los demás, aunque los demás fueran los abuelos, padres, tios.... y se encontrarán dentro de algo que no podían controlar como ellos lo hubieren deseado. Así "echarse una novia/o", era en aquellos tiempos de estrecheces, remiendos y escaseces, donde todo se miraba más que con lupa por si podía ser arreglado o aprovechado, que pensar por un momento en "echarse una novia/o", era igual que "echarse una carga" y que además podía arrastrar más complicaciones de las debidas si no se tomaban las debidas precauciones....

Por último y como ejemplo, si la persona que se echaba novia em el exterior, cuando estaba fuera, en la mili, trabajando, etc. "echarse novia/o" era distinto, la persona estaba lejos y se interpretaba como parte del hacer de la vida, como aquel que construye su propia familia y organiza sus asuntos. Sin embargo en los campos y lugares más modestos, pequeñas localidades ó pequeñas capitales el concepto de "echarse novia/o", fue distinto hasta bien entrados los setenta del S. XX.

Por tanto, como resumen y como digo, "echarse novia/o" en los momentos que conocí aquella expresión, no era considerado como un regalo ó gracia, se veía más como una carga para esas personas jóvenes que a partir de entonces, tendrían que cargar desde esa temprana "adolescencia" hasta el final de sus días con una persona que detentaba de primera, las idiosincrasia y características depositadas de los familiares que ya eran conocidos en los pueblos y pequeños lugares y que tomaban según las creencias en hijos y sobrinos el mismo especial caracter....que aquellos.